# Patching __init_subclass__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I am having trouble patching a custom class' `__init_subclass__`. I think it has to do with the way that I am binding the patched function to the class:

```
def _patched_initsubclass(cls, **kwargs):
    print(f"CLS from subclassing A: {cls}")
    super(cls, cls).__init_subclass__(**kwargs)

class A: ...

A.__init_subclass__ = _patched_initsubclass.__get__(A, A)

class B(A): ...  # Output: CLS from subclassing A: <class '__main__.A'>
```

However, I know that a properly set `__init_subclass__` should have a different output:

```
class F:

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        print(f"CLS from subclassing F: {cls}")
        pass

class C(F): ...  # Output: CLS from subclassing F: <class '__main__.C'>
```

i.e. `cls` in the super class' `__init_subclass__` definition should be the subclass when subclassed. I've tried to find the correct way to bind the dunder method through different SO posts plus the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods), but haven't been able to find the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `super` is invalid; it's supposed to be passed the type of the class that it's being called from (e.g. the class it was defined in) and the actual type it was passed (the class it was called on), so `super(cls, cls)` is lying; your explicit use of the descriptor protocol function `__get__` prebound it to `A` (bypassing the descriptor protocol when it's invoked on `B`), so it always says "I'm being called from `A` with an `A`" even when it's actually invoked on something else.

What you want isn't easy to do the correct way; [your approach of making it a `classmethod` (which means it actually gets `B`, not `A`, as expected) and calling `super(cls, None)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65206993/364696), is still wrong, even if it happens to work by coincidence here. You're telling `super` to traverse the MRO of the `None` object and call the first `__init_subclass__` it finds after `B` in the MRO. Apparently, even though `B` isn't in the MRO (which *should* be an error [according to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super): "If the second argument is an object, `isinstance(obj, type)` must be true. If the second argument is a type, `issubclass(type2, type)` must be true."; c'est la vie), it silently returns `object.__init_subclass__` and calls it; it works only because `object.__init_subclass__` doesn't do anything and doesn't object to being called.

The only way to do this correctly is to make a new version of the `_patched_initsubclass` for each class to patch that knows which class it's patching. Bonus, while doing this, you can make the closure in a way that enables zero-arg `super()`  by putting `__class__` in the closure scope for the new method (zero-arg `super()` magic is accomplished by the compiler making all functions defined in a class that reference `__class__` or `super` actually closures with `__class__` visible in closure scope).

An example solution would be:

```
def make_patched_initsubclass_for(__class__):  # Receive class to patch as __class__ directly
    # Same as before, just defined inside function to get closure scope,
    # and super() is called with no arguments
    def _patched_initsubclass(cls, **kwargs):
        print(f"CLS from subclassing A: {cls}")
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)    # super() roughly equivalent to super(__class__, cls)

    # Returns a classmethod so it descriptor protocol
    # knows to provide class uniformly, never an instance
    return classmethod(_patched_initsubclass)

class A: ...

A.__init_subclass__ = make_patched_initsubclass_for(A)  # Produces valid closure for binding to A

class B(A): ...  # Output CLS from subclassing A: <class '__main__.B'>
```

If you didn't name the argument to `make_patched_initsubclass_for` `__class__` (named it `patched_cls` or somesuch), you'd have to use `super(patched_cls, cls)` instead of `super()`, but it would work either way.

Comment: Yeah, my first priority was getting the binding correct, I only realized my use of `super()` was incorrect afterwords. Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: Regarding `__class__`, is this because we have included a `class cell`?

Comment: I really appreciate the comments in your code, the breakdown makes it much more clear.

Comment: @Algebra8: `__class__` is part of [the spec for the new (as in Python 3.0) `super`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/#specification). The spec describes it as a "cell" ("a cell named `__class__` that contains the class object that the function is defined in"). "cell" is not a term I'm used to seeing, but yes, in practice it's implemented the same way closures are, so using closures explicitly (since, per the spec, "For functions defined outside a class body, `__class__` is not defined") to add what class definitions add implicitly accomplishes the same end result.

Comment: @Algebra8: By the by, I figured out why `super(cls, None)` didn't error out when the docs say it should. They used `None` as the default sentinel for the second argument, so when you did `super(cls, None)` it behaved exactly the same as `super(cls)`, which in turn appears to return an unbound `super` object that you can look up `__init_subclass__` on (which get `super`'s own empty implementation, nothing useful). I've never needed an unbound `super`, and in this case it definitely wasn't helpful, [apparently it almost never is](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236278).

Comment: Interesting, that is good to know. Thank you for sharing this :) I've honestly never had an in-depth look into super until this post, so this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that does not involve binding the pathed function through `__get__`:

```
def _patched_initsubclass(cls, **kwargs):
    print(f"CLS from subclassing A: {cls}")

    super(cls, None).__init_subclass__(**kwargs)


class A: ...


A.__init_subclass__ = classmethod(_patched_initsubclass)


class B(A): ...  # Output CLS from subclassing A: <class '__main__.B'>
```

I am still not clear on why this works: i.e. what is difference between `classmethod()` and directly binding with `__get__`.

The answer probably has to do with what `classmethod` does under the hood, so I will look into that.

I will leave this answer up for anyone else that might find it helpful, and will include any follow up info.

Comment: To be clear, what you've done is invalid, and only works because calling the super class's `__init_subclass__` didn't do anything even when done correctly. My answer has the correct way to do this (in a reusable way, so you could patch multiple classe the same way without hand-writing a `_patched_initsubclass` for each).

Comment: Oh I didn't see your answer. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I'll leave this answer here so that what you said in your answer makes sense for anyone that views it.